# node js express app serve static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to serve my static files "web.html" and "mobile.html", but send them only if the user is connected from the web/mobile.

i thought that this the code that does this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {index: false}));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
console.log("user connected");

if (req.headers['user-agent'].match('mobile')) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/mobile.html');

} else {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/web.html');
}
});
```

but this code doesn't work. from what i understood the express.static will only serve index.html when requesting '/'. is there a way to serve a specific file when requesting '/' ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your basic logic is correct; the problem is with your mobile detection.  In many mobile browsers (I just tried this on iPhone), the UA string has "Mobile" (with a capital "M"), and you're matching on a lowercase.  I changed this to:

```
if (req.headers['user-agent'].match(/\bmob/i)) {
```

`/\bmob/i` is what I usually use for mobile detection; I've found it to be really solid.  A better choice might be @user3229720's answer, which prevents you from having to worry about the messy details of UA parsing, but I thought you might want to know in more detail what's going on here.

Comment: This is correct, But am in doubt.. It will serve static files. But in my case. Desktop version is serving SSR and in mobile view its serving only client side... Any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="/scripts/script.js"></script>
```

Use the above line in the index file or the HTML file.

```
var app=express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));
```

Use this in the app.js or the starting point of your node js application.
Create an assets folder at the root level. Inside assets folder there are sub folders : Images, CSS and Scripts

Answer (score 0):

Check [express-device](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-device) out. It accomplishes what I think you are trying to do (making a mobile version and a desktop version).