# Express serve (static) Based on Device

Tags: node.js, mobile, express, npm, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get express to show customers a different site based on their device. I.e. mobile users are served the mobile app and desktop users the web-app.

This is my code:

```
var express     = require('express'),
    app         = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var ua      = req.header('user-agent');
    // Check the user-agent string to identyfy the device.
    if(/mobile|iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|opera|mini|windows\sce|palm|smartphone|iemobile|ipad|android|android 3.0|xoom|sch-i800|playbook|tablet|kindle/i.test(ua)) {

        console.log("mobile");
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/mobile-app/www'));
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/mobile-app/www/index.html');

    } else {

        console.log("web");
        app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/web-app/www'));
        res.sendfile(__dirname + '/web-app/www/index.html');

    }
});
```

Each app works fine.  However, if I change the device using Chrome web-tools and then refresh, the other device won't load.  I.e. if the first serve instance is on the web-app and I refresh on the mobile app...the mobile app won't work. If the first serve instance is on the mobile app, then refreshing onto the web app means this won't load.

Are there any ideas about how to do this better?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025169/node-js-express-app-serve-static-files

Comment: Yes thanks - I saw that question prior to posting this one. It doesn't really help as my logic is the same, yet my problem persists. I've successfully detected a mobile/desktop user.  My trouble lies after, when serving the page.

Comment: @EdStephenson Hi can u please tell me how you fix this..???

Comment: Sorry I didn't find a solution.